# How can I highlight the line number with diffadd and diffadd and diffdelete

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vimdiff, signs

I want line numbers to be highlighted for diff files depending on added lines and removed lines. For added lines, the line number should be green. For removed lines, the line number should be red. I tried the following:

```
sign define DiffAdd numhl=DiffAdd
exe ":sign place 2 name=DiffAdd group=DiffAdd file="..expand("%:p")
```

It gave me this error:

```
Not possible to change sign DiffAdd
```